# Necesito hacer una concatenación

Tags: mysql, jsp, hibernate, maven

Mi problema es que necesito meter una lista de equipos a mi base de datos pero en una columna solo se puede meter un dato. Se cae el sistema por eso, pensé en hacer una concatenación de `select` pero no se cómo, he intentado varias cosas pero no me funciona.

Código del select

```
    <div class="divD">
        <h5 style="margin-right: 450px;">Equipo</h5>
        <select  style="width: 150px; margin-right: 450px; text-align: center; " class="select" name="origenE[]" id="origenE" multiple="multiple" size="10">
            <c:forEach var="equipo" items="${equipos}"> 
                <option value="<c:out value="${equipo.codigo}"/>" >
                    <c:out value="${equipo.descripcion}" /> 
                    </option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="divB" style="margin-top:-130px;"> 
        <input class="pasarE izq" value="Pasar »" type="button"> 
        <input class="quitarE der" value="« Quitar" type="button"><br>
        <input class="pasartodosE izq" value="Todos »" type="button">
        <input class="quitartodosE der" value="« Todos" type="button">
    </div>  
      <br>
    <div class="divA">
        <h5 style="margin-right: -450px; margin-top:-150px;">Equipo asignados</h5>
         <spring:bind path="RESA.codigo">
            <select style="width: 150px;  margin-right: -450px; text-align: center;" class="select" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" id="destinoE" multiple="multiple" size="10">
                <c:forEach var="equipo" items="${RESA.codigo}"> 
                    <option value="<c:out value="${equipo.codigo}"/> ">
                        <c:out value="${equipo.descripcion}" /> 
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
         </spring:bind> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Podrias reescribir cual es tu problema, no te he entendido bien

Comment: @jasilva mi problema es que tengo una lista de equipos donde se puede escoger de 1 o mas equipos para una reservacion pero cuando solo se escoge un equipo guarda en la bd de forma correcta pero a la hora de insertar dos o mas equipos se cae ya que no se puede meter varios elementos a una columna, entonces una posible solucion era hacer una concatenacion y guardarla como una cadena

Answer (score 1):

Si recibes tu lista de equipos en formato de un arreglo, puedes transformalo en json, asi se almacenara como cadena y al recuperar puedes decodificar para transformalo en arreglo nuevamente. Aunque no es recomenadable guardar una lista en un campo, lo mas probable es que debas analizar el modelo de tu base de datos y buscar una mejor solución para la estructura de tu base de datos

Comment: intentare hacer lo del json, la verdad esque tuve que cambiar a ese modo ya que la solución anterior me estaba dando muchos problemas y por eso elegí mejor usar una cadena